# Why does 0.ToString("#.##") return an empty string instead of 0.00 or at least 0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tostring

Why does `0.ToString("#.##")` return an empty string? Shouldn't it be `0.00` or **at least 0**?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

`#` in the string format indicate that the value is optional. If you wish to get the output `0.00` you need the following:

```
0.ToString("0.00");
```

See [here for the custom numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) that can be passed to this method.

Comment: One thing still confused me that why the result is not 0. Because 0 is not optional. Is empty makes sense?

Answer (score 152):

Because in a format string, the `#` is used to signify an optional character placeholder; it's only used if *needed* to represent the number.

If you do this instead: `0.ToString("0.##");` you get: `0`

Interestingly, if you do this: `0.ToString("#.0#");` you get: `.0`

If you want all three digits: `0.ToString("0.00");` produces: `0.00`

---

From the comments to this answer, your argument seems to be,

> it should show '0', because why would anyone ever want to see an empty string if the numeric value is 0?

The response is simple: *You have the choice* how you wish it to be displayed. That's what the custom format strings are for. **You have simply chosen the incorrect format string for your needs**.

Answer (score 20):

According to the documentation about the *Digit Placeholder*.

> If the value being formatted has a digit in the position where the '#' appears in the format string, then that digit is copied to the result string. Otherwise, nothing is 
>   stored in that position in the result string. This specifier never displays the '0' character if it is not a significant digit, even if '0' is the only digit in the string. It will 
>   display the '0' character if it is a significant digit in the number being displayed. The "##" format string causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding 
>   the decimal, where rounding away from zero is always used. For example, formatting 34.5 with "##" would result in the value 35.

If you want the zero to display use the *Zero PlaceHolder*

> f the value being formatted has a digit in the position where the '0' appears in the format string, then that digit is copied to the result string. The position of the 
>   leftmost '0' before the decimal point and the rightmost '0' after the decimal point determines the range of digits that are always present in the result string.
>   The "00" specifier causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding the decimal, where rounding away from zero is always used. For example, formatting 
>   34.5 with "00" would result in the value 35.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `0.ToString("#,##; #,##;0")`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SectionSeparator

The first section applies to positive values, the second section applies to negative values, and the third section applies to zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
0.ToString("#0.##")
```

`0` after `#` will ensure to set output value to 0 if the value is 0 else it will display the value.
So `0.0.ToString("#0.##")=0.00` and `10.ToString("#.##")=10.00`