# MVC renders Double as empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Within a view I have the following code:

```
@foreach (var ce in Model.MyObjectCollection)
{
    <p>
        Target: @ce.Target.ToString("#.##")%
        <br/>
        Level: @ce.Level.ToString("#.##")%
    </p>
}
```

If either the value of `Target` or `Level` is 0.00, then MVC simply renders that out as an empty string.  Debugging shows the value of each to be **0.00**.

I need zero values to render as 0.00%.

Can anyone advise if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001603/why-does-0-tostring-return-an-empty-string-instead-of-0-00-or-at-least-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [# format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD) won't display zeros

> Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that is being displayed.

You can use the [0 specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#Specifier0) instead

```
ToString("0.00")%
```

Comment: Argh.  Stupid mistake!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use zeros instead of #:

```
@ce.Target.ToString("0.00")%
```