# Formatting a number to have trailing zeros using ToString() in C#

Tags: c#, format, decimal, tostring, trailing

I want to format a number with the help of `ToString()`.

I've been using `<myVar>.ToString("#.##");` and getting `13.1` and `14` and `22.22`.

How can I get `13.10`, `14.00` and `22.22` instead?

I don't want it to hide the zeros like now.

Comment: As Royi states, use that format. It would also help to [look at the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx), which explains the differences between the custom format strings.

Answer (score 20):

Because in a format string, the # is used to signify an optional character placeholder; it's only used if needed to represent the number.

If you do this instead: `0.ToString("0.##");` you get: `0`

Interestingly, if you do this: `0.ToString("#.0#");` you get: `.0`

If you want all three digits: `0.ToString("0.00");` produces: `0.00`

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9001603/2050745)

Answer (score 12):

You can use [the numeric (`"N"`) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) with `2` precision as well.

```
Console.WriteLine((13.1).ToString("N2")); // 13.10
Console.WriteLine((14).ToString("N2"));   // 14.00
Console.WriteLine((22.22).ToString("N2")); // 22.22
```

Remember this format specifier uses `CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) *by default*. If yours is not `.`, you can use a culture that has `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)) in `ToString` method as a second parameter.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible by using zero format specifier:

```
.ToString(".00");
```

An example:

```
int k=25;
string str_1 = k.ToString(".00"); // Output: "25,00"
```

The hash sign `#` means that value is optional. For example:

```
string str_2 = 0.ToString("0.##");// Output: "0"
```